# GADT vs Existentially quantified types (*forall*)

Tags: haskell, types, gadt, existential-type

One can use *GADT* to express *Existentially quantified types*.

I see that *GADT* is more generic - [data-type-extensions](http://www.haskell.org/ghc/docs/latest/html/users_guide/data-type-extensions.html), paragraph section 7.4.7

When it's better to use *Existentially quantified types* then *GADT*? Are there any drawbacks using *GADT* compared to *Existentially quantified types*?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

GADTs came along later than existentials, and they generalise them. I'm not aware of any drawbacks and would always use GADT syntax in new code as it's much clearer.

The [documentation](http://www.haskell.org/ghc/docs/latest/html/users_guide/data-type-extensions.html#gadt-style) confirms this:

> Notice that GADT-style syntax generalises existential types.

Comment: That's not quite true, the old broken behaviour was for data type contexts, not existentials. This works http://lpaste.net/108693

Comment: The difference you mentioned is not the difference between GADTs and existentials. Both provide class context when you match against the constructor.

Comment: Thanks for the correction, my mistake. I misread the bit talking about the difference between vanilla H98 and GADTs and didn't think about it properly.

Comment: Yes, the GADT syntax is much cleaner, I too would advise sticking to GADTs.

Answer (score 2):

If you use the newest version of GHC, then there are no drawbacks I'm aware of. But in older versions you could combine GADTs and GeneralizedNewtypeDeriving in a type-unsafe way. I don't think the same was possible with ExistentialQuantification.

Comment: Can you please expand on how combining GND with "GADTs as existentials" can lead to type unsafety? I think it is "type-level programming" part of GADTs that leads to unsafe behavior not the existential one.

Comment: @maxtaldykin I don't think it can. I recall GADTs are equivalent in power to combining existential quantification with type equality contexts, and it's the latter that are obviously broken by the old unrestricted newtype deriving.

Comment: @maxtaldykin I think it was only due GND not properly checking type equalities (which I believe is fixed now): http://joyoftypes.blogspot.com/2012/08/generalizednewtypederiving-is.html

Comment: @maxtaldykin, sure. Check this out: http://migmit.livejournal.com/44473.html — text is in Russian, but the code should be clear enough. And yes, it's fixed now.

Comment: There are no existentially quantified variables in your code. My point is that it is safe enough to use GADTs instead of ExistentialQuantification.

Comment: Of course there are no existentially quantified variables in my code, because you CAN'T do such a thing with existential quantification. THAT'S WHY existential quantification is safer than GADTs in older versions of GHC.